# ProgressDialog not responding

Tags: java, android

Hello guys why when i add ProgressDialog it become not responding

```
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AppsInspectorActivity.this, "", 
                    "Scanning package " + pkgInfo.packageName, true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
```

at above `Log.v(TAG, "Scanning package " + pkgInfo.packageName);`

```
private List<PackageInfo> getAdPackages() {
```

[HEAVY STUFF]

```
    return new ArrayList<PackageInfo>(adPackages);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "it become not responding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASyncTask is the way to go. just override doInBackground(). and use a Handler class for stopping (dismiss()) the progressDialog.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog
seems useful..

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html
very in-depth version..

Comment: how to extend ? it is  `extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {` ?

Comment: it's arg list is flux, im currently using "extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>" and "protected String doInBackground(String... urls)". if you need a more complex structure i would bind it to the scope (private member/field).

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what not responding means? Does the dialog never display, or simply not dismiss when you press Back? When the operation is complete, try to dismiss the dialog with:

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to take a guess at the problem, if your saying that the progress dialog freezes and the app becomes non responsive, it appears that you haven't threaded the long term process that the dialog is designed to represent. By default all code is ran on the UI thread, so if your process takes to long, the screen doesn't update and the user gets the notification of death (Not responding). You should thread long term processes (preferably in an async task) and post updates to the progress dialog as needed in the onProgressUpdate method.

Comment: So if I use asyn task which section should I extend? `private list`?

Comment: You should create a new class that extends async task, start the dialog in the pre execute, and clear the dialog in the post execute, and post updates as needed in the progress update section.

Comment: Also: if it isn't obvious migrate your long term process into the "doInBackground"

Comment: Thanks!  I will try it out, asyn task is very new to me